# sometime sails js session does not destroy

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have create a web application using sails js. Following is logout function.

```
logout: function(req, res) {
      req.session.destroy(function(err) {
           res.redirect('/');
      });
}
```

Sometime user does not logout from one click. But anyway user is redirecting to my home page. Then I have to click again logout button to logout the user.

Comment: Instead of redirect from app, if you use a javascript redirect (set a flag on destroy, that flag inserts a js redirect in view), does it work ?

Comment: thank you arkoak. Is there a way to pass data from controller to javascript.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Even i'm struggling with it.

Answer (score 5):

Send them to a logout page instead of a redirect or put a timeout in the callback.

```
logout: function(req, res) {
      req.session.destroy(function(err) {
           return res.view('/logout');
      });
}
```

or

```
logout: function(req, res) {
      req.session.destroy(function(err) {
           timeout(function(){
               return res.redirect('/');
           }, 1000);
      });
}
```

Comment: ya, depending on the version of sails,express,express-connect their are issues with a redirect. Also depends on how your session is set, if that does not work I would update your question if its a Redis session, or memory or purely cookie?

Comment: I tried using above method. But did not work for me. I don't use Redis or cookie. I just assign values to session variables.

Comment: Oh, my code above did not RETURN res.view() . I would try that.

Comment: This seems to be an unresolved issue, most authentication examples out there are using passport, I am rebuilding a legacy php app in node/sails and i am facing this issue, Sometimes sessions are not destoyed and my policies fail.

Comment: This continues to work fine for me, however I did stop using sails because the inability to get express updated quick enough which I assume is where this bug lies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
logout: function(req, res) {
        // clear login sessions here
        req.session.destroy(function(err) {
          setTimeout(function(){
            return res.redirect('/login');
          }, 2500); // redirect wait time 2.5 seconds
        });
      }
```

Just giving a delay for sails js to clear the session,
Working fine for me...